# How can I write "How many data are there?" from my database to label2.text?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;initial catalog = ELibraryInformation;integrated security = true"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(ELibraryInformation) FROM Id WHERE ELibraryInformation = @Id", baglanti))
        {

            baglanti.Open();
            komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", label2.Text);

        }
   }
}
```

I want to show how many Id's are from database to `label.Text`.

Comment: Using the duplicate you can write: `label2.Text = komut.ExecuteScalar().ToString();` after the parameter assignment.

Comment: I did what you said and got the following error even though there is an "Id" column in my database's chart => 'Invalid object name' Id '.'